# Why do I get 'cannot convert type 'IEnumerable<myType>' to 'myType' on this LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

Object is simple, it's a rate of pay:

```
public class RateOfPay
{
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm trying to get it like this:

```
IEnumerable<T> rates = GetRates(); 
/*  
    actual collection is DevExpress XPCollection<RateOfPay> 
    which implements IEnumerable<T>
*/

var rate = from r in rates where r.End == null select r; // err here
```

It's odd because the intellisense works fine on r, but it's saying that r is an IEnumerable collection?

What am I missing?

Comment: What's `T`?  Did you mean `IEnumerable<RateOfPay> rates = GetRates();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a collection, it's an IEnumerable().Where(rate => rate.End == null) which is all rates that match that criteria.

You're missing the .FirstOrDefault() on your IEnumerable, can't tell you the statement query syntax though..

Should look like

```
var rate = rates.FirstOrDefault(r => r.End == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code sample the `IEnumerable<T>` collection is not bound to a particular type.  Hence there is no way to call the `End` property on the value.  Is there a type in the code?

If not the following could fix the problem

```
var rate = from r in rates.Cast<RateOfPay>() where r.End == null select r;
```

If on the other hand there is just a type and you are looking to have `rate` be a single value then try the following.

```
var filtered = from r in rates where r.End == null select r;
RateOfPay v1 = filtered.Single(); // If only 1 should ever match
RateOfPay v2 = filtered.First();  // if several could match and you just want 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> > var rate = from r in rates where r.End == null select r; // err here

Hmmmm....  Is `rate` really declared ar `var`, or is that really `Rate rate =' ??

The reason I ask, is because the linq query is going to return an IEnumerable (with likely just one item).  You probably actually want:

```
Rate rate = (from r in rates where r.End == null select r).First();
```

which could be reduced to just:

```
Rate rate = rates.First(r=>r.End == null);
```